# how to tell which module an address belong to in GDB

Tags: debugging, x86, gdb

Most of the times when I'm debugging I get to some address in memory and I want to know which module 
that addresses it belongs to and every time I had to go list the proc maps and start looking for a minute or so,
so if there is an easy way to do it,
you give it the address and it looks for which module that address belongs to.

Most of my time I'm debugging files with no source code at all so I will include the tag of assembly because there is a relation between gdb and assembly in the work that I do, and I believe that most of the users who browse x86 tag have used GDB in one way or another.

Comment: I actually needed something like this once as well, and implemented a [find-library](https://github.com/ssbssa/gdb/commit/cafb6d613a42bfaf151a794846a1c820e5581d59) command for this.

Answer (score 3):

> you give it the address and it looks for which module that address belongs to.

By "which module" you appear to mean "which shared library". If so:

```
(gdb) info symbol $addr
```

will give you direct answer.

Comment: that's not working for me when I do it it gives me No symbol matches 0x7ffff7fddf10.

Comment: @zerocool The `0x7ffff7fddf10` looks like a stack address, which doesn't belong to any "module" (whatever you mean by that word).

Comment: it belongs to ld-2.27.so but as you said it's in a memory region that is Dynamique (I'm not sure if it was the stack or the heap but from what I can tell it's the dynamic memory)

Comment: here is an image of the  proc map  https://i.ibb.co/DCvSDDt/gdbpic.png